# Nested try/catch Blocks: Two Different Implementations

Tags: java

I have been spending sometime relearning Java through a textbook I used in undergrad. At the tail end of their explanation on exceptions, they present the following code:

```
public class ReadingObjects {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("objects");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            try{
                while(true){
                    Auto temp = (Auto)ois.readObject();
                    System.out.println(temp);
                }
            }
            catch(EOFException eofe){
                System.out.println("End of file has been reached.");
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
                System.out.println(cnfe.getMessage());
            }
            finally{
                System.out.println("Closing file. . .");
                ois.close();
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
            System.out.println("Unable to find the objects file.");
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The book's reasoning for using two `try/catch` blocks is because the program will throw an `EOFException` no matter what since the `ObjectInputStream` class has no means to check if there are any more objects in the file (it does not have an equivalent to `hasNext()` that the `Scanner` class offers). Also, once an exception is thrown, any code that was written after the point in the `try` that generated the exception will be ignored; Java will go straight to the `catch` block for the exception in question. Hence, the inner `try/catch` block takes care of the `EOFException` and then jumps into the `finally` portion. The outer `try` block takes care of any of the remaining exceptions.

My main question is why use 2 `try/catch` blocks for this? It seems like it's an overly complicated solution. To be sure I was having the right understanding on this, I went ahead and wrote up the following code which uses only one `try/catch` block:

```
public class ReadingObjects {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("objects");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        try{
            while(true){
                Auto temp = (Auto)ois.readObject();
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
        }
        catch(EOFException eofe){
            System.out.println("End of file has been reached.");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
            System.out.println(cnfe.getMessage());
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
            System.out.println("Unable to find the objects file.");
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            System.out.println("Closing file. . .");
            ois.close();
        }

    }

}
```

With the second solution, I still obtain the same output as I did with the first (the book's) solution. Are there any reservations to doing it this way? Should I be wary of adding the throws declaration in my `main` method?

Any clarification and input on this would be appreciated.

Comment: In the first example `ois` will not be null in the inner `try` so in the finally it can be referenced and closed.  If you check for `null` in you second example it may be OK

Comment: `ois.close()` can throw an `IOException`, that's why they nested the blocks.

Comment: @nullpointer  - That would make sense! In that case, you still have the outer `try/catch` to handle the `IOException`

Answer (score 0):

These are two different techniques for handling exception. In first code you are using nested try catch block in sometimes a situation may arise where a part of a block may cause one error and the entire block itself may cause another error. In such cases, exception handlers have to be nested.

in second code you are using try with multiple catch blocks. Both are given as same output but these two are different techniques only for handle the exception.

Answer (score 0):

`ois.close()` might throw an exception as well. It will be handled gracefully in the first implementation but bubble-up in the second...

Comment: Are you saying that  because`ois.close()` might throw an `IOException` as well? That is what nullpointer mentioned.

Comment: Yes. This is very unlikely when read operations are performed, but during writing the `close()` might involve flushing the buffer, which invokes physical I/O - be it over the filesystem, network or any other medium.

Answer (score 0):

The book's explanation doesn't hold water. The `EOFException` and `ClassNotFoundException` could just as easily be caught at the outer level. The real difference would be if the `ClassNotFoundException` was caught *inside* the while loop, soyou could continue reading other objects you might have the .class file for. However that exception really indicates a deployment problem, and so it may not make much sense to continue reading the stream.

Comment: I don't quite follow your explanation. . . Are you referring to the `ClassNotFoundException` being caught inside the `while` for the first or second implementation?